# Open-source implementations of a photoshop-like quick select algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, gimp

Are there any open-source implementations of an graph-cut algorithm similar to that used for Photoshop's quick select tool? I'm researching for a personal project of making a GIMP tool\plugin similar to PS's tool, but I'm wondering if it's been done before.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure How exactly quick select works, but if i had to implement such task - my first starting approach would be to detect area of similar colors. For this one should:

1. Convert RGB color space to [HSV or HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).
2. Run [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) algorithm on Hue values.
3. [Sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29) edge points to reduce data size.
4. Run points [clustering algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).
5. Filter-out points which doesn't belongs to nearest cluster.
6. Run [convex hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to dismiss cluster inner edges.

I'm not saying that this approach will work, but still i think that this is an interesting idea to explore.

Good luck!

Comment: Quite interesting. However, this is an combination of algorithms, and I was looking for implementations.

Comment: I think it also stores a mask of the adjustments the user made to the selection (adding and removing parts from the selection).

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper called "Paint Selection" published at Siggraph 2009. It describes a method very similar to Photoshop's quick select tool. You can access the paper from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/PaintSelection_SIGGRAPH09.pdf

Comment: When linking to an external resource, please include a summary (even if brief) of the contents so that your answer remains useful if the linked resource ever disappears.